# Divide and Conquer matrices to calculate determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Do the determinant of a matrix equal to the determinant of submatrices?

$$
det\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots & a_{1k} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots & a_{2k} \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \dots & a_{3k} \\
\vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & a_{n3} & \dots & a_{nk} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

equals

$$
det\begin{pmatrix}
  det\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix} & det\begin{pmatrix}a_{13} & a_{14}\\ a_{23} & a_{24}\end{pmatrix} & \dots\\
\ddots & \vdots \\
  det\begin{pmatrix}a_{(n-1)1} & a_{(n-1)2}\\ a_{(n-2)1} & a_{(n-2)2}\end{pmatrix} & det\begin{pmatrix}a_{(n-1)3} & a_{(n-1)4}\\ a_{(n-2)3} & a_{(n-2)4}\end{pmatrix} & \dots\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And of course I would like to know if it can be generalized from 2x2 to mxm division.

Answer (score 6):

As others point out, your attempted formula is not correct.  However, there is a rather amazing formula that is true for the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix $M$.  Let $M^{NW}$ denote the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix of $M$ obtained by using the upperleft most entries (i.e. crossing out the bottom row and last column).  The NW stands for northwest.  Similarly define $M^{NE}$, $M^{SW}$, $M^{SE}$.  Finally, denote $M^C$ the $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ submatrix obtained by taking the center submatrix (i.e. cross out the top and bottom rows, and the first and last columns).  Then
$$
\det(M) = \frac{\det(M^{NW}) \det(M^{SE}) - \det(M^{NE}) \det(M^{SW})}{\det(M^C)}.
$$

Comment: That sounds like a good formula. I would like to see some proof. Can you mention some links?

Comment: @user2255279 This is "Lewis Carroll's identity", and it leads to a calculation that involves only $2\times 2$ subdeterminants, albeit much more laborious than you might naively have hopes.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't just use sub-determinants like that. To see why not, consider the determinant of the matrix
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&-1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
Now, if we were to divide it into parts, you'd get
$$
\det\left( \begin{matrix} \det\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)&\det\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\-1&0\end{matrix}\right)\\\det\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)&\det\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right) \end{matrix}\right)=\det\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right) = 1
$$
But the determinant of our original matrix is actually 2.
More generally, consider that one of the terms in the determinant of the $4\times4$ matrix will include $a_{11}$, $a_{23}$, $a_{32}$, and $a_{44}$ - notice that each of these is in a different one of the four $2\times2$ submatrices.

Answer (score 2):

No (you can work out an example with a small matrix).  You might be interested in the Laplace expansion, though.

Comment: It does not make sense to apply it on 3x3 matrix, as right most rows will have no pair. But what about 4x4 matrix?

Comment: @user2255279 Yes, of course, but the answer "no" still holds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the devellopment towards a line or a column. You have:

devellopement towards jth columns:

$$\det{A}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,j} {\rm Cof}_{i,j}$$

devellopement towards ith rows:

$$\det{A}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j} {\rm Cof}_{i,j}$$

Where ${\rm Cof}_{i,j}=(-1)^{i+j}\det{M_{i,j}}$ and $M_{i,j}$ is the matrice A without ith rows and jth columns.

I am not sure about the efficience of this method as you have to sum n,  $(n-1)*(n-1)$ derterminants. Which lead to $n!$ steps...

The method is interesting when you have a line with only few non-zero values, ie sparse matrices.